# Changing the background of the google search page using my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first chrome plugin that will open the Google page with random pictures as its back ground when user clicks on new tab button. As of now , I am not very sure ,how to change the Google search page background with random images . Is there any api provided by google ? As for as i googled , earlier Google had "change background image" icon but now they stopped such support. Here how can i change the background of the google search page to different color or with different backgroung image. I tried with following js code.Please suggest or redirect me towards the right approach.Any help will be appreciated.

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
};
```

Also the following script will change the background of the current html page 
but how to change the background of the third party page by injecting this.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('xyz.png')";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself .

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("chrome-extension://@'+chrome.runtime.id+'/icon.png")';
};
```

This loads the background picture for my google search page.
Thanks.

Comment: Adding to this that now you'd want to use `__MSG_@@extension_id__` I believe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like body is worng you should replace that with element. Using F12 inspector in chrome you see that background-color is defined with

```
element.style {
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

If you don't wan't to code, there are already multiple background plugins, and chrome theme plugin with lots of themes, where I'm sure that some of them accept custom image/color.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have found the exact answer that i posted below.